# How to provide a URL link from one app's template to the homepage which is in the root urls.py in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I have to give a link to the homepage which happens to be the login page of my website, from an app's template, that is:

```
<small style="margin-top: 5px;">To login<a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="login">Click Here</a></small>
```

Now, the problem in the `URL tag` is that the link is available in the root `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this. There is a `'bboard'` application, the `login` and `info` `views` are in the application. In the urls.py file (the `configuration folder` where the settings.py file is located) I register the import of the application with the desired view:

```
from bboard.views import login
```

**Replace `bboard` with the name of your application everywhere.**

urls.py(configuration folder)

```
from bboard.views import login

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('bboard.urls')),
    path('login/', login, name='login'),

]
```

urls.py(application)

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('info/', info, name='info'),
   ]
```

views.py

```
def login(request):

    return HttpResponseNotFound("<h2>12345</h2>")

def info(request):

    return render(request, 'bboard/templ.html')
```

templates

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Link</a>
```